# GetProcAddress() on GetModuleHandle(nullptr) fails under MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw

I'm using `GetModuleHandle(nullptr)` to get the handle for the current process and then using `GetProcAddress()` on the handle to lookup a function inside the calling executable.

This works perfectly when compiled with MSVC, but when using either Clang or GCC under MinGW, the `GetProcAddress()` call fails with error code 127 (`ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND`) and returns `nullptr`.

The function I am looking up is defined as:

```
extern "C"
{
    void NOVA_API local_lookup_test(void* thing)
    {
        std::stringstream* out = static_cast<std::stringstream *>(thing);
        *out << "YouFoundMe!\n";
    }
}
```

With the `NOVA_API` macro defined as:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define NOVA_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define NOVA_API __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#endif
```

The function is being exported correctly, with no mangling, as running `rm` on the executable shows it has been exported:

```
$ nm NovaTest.exe | grep local_lookup_test
0000000000421160 T local_lookup_test
```

I have tried numerous ways of messing with the names, marking for export in different ways, using different calling conventions, but only under MinGW will `GetProcAddress()` fail.

The code I'm using for getting the function pointer:

```
typedef void(*FuncType)(void*);
HMODULE handle = GetModuleHandle(nullptr);
auto func = (FuncType)GetProcAddress(handle, "local_lookup_test");
```

edit:

`GetModuleHandle(nullptr)` returns a handle to the calling process, which I use to dynamically lookup function names inside the calling `.exe` file.

The handle returned by `GetModuleHandle(nullptr)` is not `nullptr`, and no error is seen by `GetLastError()`, so to my knowledge the handle should be valid.

Comment: The title of the question emphasis that `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` is a condition for the problem to occur. You didn't explain in the question how this conditions comes in. You further didn't show if the `handle` is NULL before the call to `GetProcAddress`. Didn't you get a handle or do you assume you got an invalid handle?

Comment: I emphasize GetModuleHandle(NULL) as passing NULL to GetModuleHandle is used to get a handle to the calling process [outlined here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199(v=vs.85).aspx). GetModuleHandle(NULL) returns a non null handle and no error is given by GetLastError().

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place?  There is NO good reason for an EXE to use `GetProcAddress()` to get a pointer to its own functions.  It has direct access to them: `FuncType func = &local_lookup_test;` What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am using the [hashlink](https://hashlink.haxe.org/) virtual machine to embed a scripting language into my game engine. Haxe allows me to specify external native code that can be called inside the virtual machine by a script. To do this I can tell it to lookup function pointers by name in the host executable like this
`@hlNative("builtin", "local_lookup_test") public static function local_lookup_test() {}`
This uses the internal lookup into the executable that I'm having trouble with.
Because the functions it needs are looked by a name that changes at runtime I need to lookup in the exe.

Comment: There is also a mechanism for specifying a dll to lookup function pointers in but that will needlessly complicate the build and ergonomics of working with hashlink by forcing me to compile as a dll and use a tiny .exe wrapper.

Comment: `nm` shows that the symbol exists. `DUMPBIN /EXPORTS` will tell you whether it's exported.

Comment: Why is `__declspec(dllexport)` only used for `#ifdef _MSC_VER`? I think you need `#ifdef _WIN32` instead.

Comment: I am compiling with both msvc, clang and gcc on windows which don't all support `declspec(dllexport)` properly to my knowledge.